# Treat command provided as argument as plain text

Tags: listings, arguments, detokenize

I find myself struggling with a supposedly simple task but after several hours of searching and trial&error I finally give up. I probably still lack the deeper understanding of LaTeX and its internals.

In the following MWE I would like to refer to commands and macros (e.g., `\usepackage`) by printing them as plain text (step 1).
To get rid of the `\textbackslash`, I thought I could wrap them in an inline listing (step 2). This still works as expected. Trouble started when I tried to create a macro for that (step 3). As an argument to my macro, commands are not interpreted as text but as the commands themselves, I guess, causing an `Improper alphabetic constant` error in my example.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\commandToText}[1]{\lstinline{#1}} %step 3

\begin{document}  
\textbackslash usepackage %step 1
\lstinline{\usepackage} %step 2
\commandToText{\usepackage} %step 3
\end{document}
```

After some search I found `\detonkenize` to probably be the command needed to fix this.
At least `\newcommand{\commandToText}[1]{\detokenize{#1}}` prints the argument as plain text regardless of whether or not a command is provided as input.

Unfortunately, wrapping the argument with an inline listing `\newcommand{\commandToText}[1]{\lstinline{\detokenize{#1}}}` pdflatex does not terminate anymore.

I wonder if detokenizing is the best approach to interpret commands given as arguments as plain text. Maybe there are other alternatives? Or can `lstinline` be convinced to work with the detokenized commands?

**UPDATE:**
I realize from the comments and the answer that my MWE is too minimal as it leaves out two aspects:

- I use the `listings` package in various configurations (e.g., for code, JSON, explanations) and appreciate the possibility to easily define and adapt the common style to my needs. Alternatives like `\texttt` or `\verb` to me felt like being less convenient. But if the answer is, my goal cannot be achieved using `\lstinline` then one of these might be the alternative.
- `\commandToText` should be able to receive further decorations. For example, currently I use the package `realboxes` to further highlight the text: `\newcommand{\commandToText}[1]{\Colorbox{yellow}{\lstinline{#1}}}`.
  To my knowledge, just wrapping `\lstinline` without specifying arguments (as proposed by Skillmon and egreg) would not allow to do so.

I wonder why step 3 above does not work. I would have expected `\lstinline` to already convert to plain text. It does so if it is called outside of a macro. But if it is used on the argument of a macro it doesn't.
Similarly, `\newcommand{\commandToText}[1]{\Colorbox{yellow}{\verb|#1|}}` does not work as the argument seems to be interpreted before `\verb` is applied. I guess, this is related to how these commands are expanded?

Comment: do you need `\lstinline` here? why?

Comment: don't you just  want `\newcommand{\commandToText}[1]{\texttt{\string#1}}` ?

Comment: You could as well curry the argument: `\newcommand\commandToText{\lstinline}` should work.

Comment: Maybe it's best if you tell us what exactly you want, as this seems like an xy-problem to me. Maybe the best approach to solve your issue is neither one of those steps.

Comment: @Skillmon at the top level, yes but `lstinline` still an odd choice if there is no syntax to parse

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hence the second comment :P

Comment: or simply `\verb|\usepackage|` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for the comments. I updated my question to take them into account.

Comment: it's not that you can not use lstinline it's just that it seems inappropriate, the point of listings package is to apply some simple grammars to syntax-highlight a code listing. If you know in advance there is no syntax just a single word preceded by a backslash it will be doing an awful lot of work, none of which is used other than the font change

Comment: I got to admit that for this specific use case it might be overkill. So far, however, ease of use and unifying my "interface" outweighed the performance hit this may cause.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Given the box I'd like to put the commands in, how would I use `\verb` to get the desired result? `\newcommand{\commandToText}[1]{\Colorbox{lightgray}{\verb|#1|}}` still won't do the trick as `#1` seems to be interpreted before `\verb` gets applied.

Comment: @Johnson yes verb, like lstinline has to be top level but you can use `\texttt{\string#1}` anywhere, including colorbox.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think, everything boils down to that last comment. Why do these commands have to be top level? If you can formulate an answer to that and mention your alternative with `\texttt` this might conclude this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

commands like `\verb`, `\lstinline`, `\makeatother` work by changing catcodes, that is, the way characters read from file are tokenised.
`\usepackage` is normally a single csname token but

```
\verb|\usepackage|
```

makes `\`  a normal catcode 12 character so `\usepackage` is 11 character tokens.

However if you do (any) construct such as `\fbox{\verb|\usepackage|}` the argument is tokenised while scanning for the closing brace, so by the time `\verb` is called there is a single csname token between the `|`. The catcode of `\`  gets changed but has no effect as there is no `\`  character being tokenised.

Conversely `\string` (and `\detokenize`) do not rely on changing tokenisation, they convert the supplied *tokens* and produce character tokens.

so you can nest this as

```
\newcommand{\commandToText}[1]{\colorbox{red}{\texttt{\string#1}}}
```

or whatever you need.

A bit verbose but detailed explanation can be found on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_TeX_macros_actually_work%3A_Part_6#Arguments_are_first_converted_to_tokens).

Comment: I assumed the problem might lie in my understanding of the workflow. You just made me aware of the fact that macro arguments are first converted to tokens before any further processing. I was expecting a more recursive behavior.

Comment: @Johnson tex is a macro processor not a functional language: arguments are not processed at all (other than tokenization) they are simply spliced in to the replacement text unevaluated.

Comment: By processing I was referring to expansion of the nested macros/commands.

Comment: @Johnson yes but the unprocessed arguments are dropped in to `#1`, `#2`, ... then processing starts at the start of the replacement text. So you can go `\commandToText{\wibble}`  it does not matter `\wibble`  is not defined, it just gets inserted as `\colorbox{red}{\texttt{\string\wibble}}` then `\colorbox` processing starts, and eventually `\string` will be reached which will make `\ w i b b l e`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print a single command name at a time, the simplest way is to define

```
\newcommand{\commandToText}[1]{\texttt{\string#1}}
```

The `\texttt` is used in order to have more visual distinction between normal text and command names.

If you want to do more complex tasks, you can define

```
\newcommand{\commandToText}{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]}
```

but this cannot be used in the argument to another command. It leaves the determination of the argument to `\lstinline`, so there is no untimely tokenization.

Comment: I updated my question to take your answer into account. Btw. my highest appreciation for you and also @David Carlisle. I always wonder how ppl. manage to be so involved. Every second question I come across is at least commented by one of you.